# tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath not called in custom view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I made a `popupView` to select some object in my project.

Everything works fine except the `tableViewDelegate` is not called.(`DataSource` works fine)

I logged value of `tableView.delegate` from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.It also have the correct value.

Below is my code.

```
protocol AddressSelectPopupDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {

func addressSelectPopup(selectedContact: Contact) }

class AddressSelectPopupView: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

weak var parentView: UIView!
weak var delegate: AddressSelectPopupDelegate!


var contactList : [Contact] = []
var selectedContact : Contact?


class func addressSelectPopupView(parentView: UIView, delegate: AddressSelectPopupDelegate) -> AddressSelectPopupView
{
    var popupView = UINib(nibName: "AddressSelectPopupView", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! AddressSelectPopupView
    popupView.parentView = parentView
    popupView.delegate = delegate

    popupView.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "AddressInfoTableViewCell", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier:"AddressInfoTableViewCell")
    popupView.tableView.delegate = popupView
    popupView.tableView.dataSource = popupView

    return popupView
}

//MARK: - Public Interface
func popup()
{
    self.parentView.addSubview(self)

    self.loadContactList()
}

func dismiss()
{
    self.removeFromSuperview()
}

//MARK: - Private Interface
private func loadContactList()
{
    ConnectionManager.connection.loadContactList({ [weak self](contactList) -> Void in

        self!.contactList = contactList

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            if self!.tableView != nil
            {
                self!.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        })

    }, failure: { [weak self] () -> Void in
        self!.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}

//MARK: - UITableView Delegate & DataSource
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return contactList.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:AddressInfoTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AddressInfoTableViewCell") as! AddressInfoTableViewCell

    let contact = contactList[indexPath.row]

    cell.contact = contact

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    selectedContact = contactList[indexPath.row]

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {

    selectedContact = contactList[indexPath.row]

    return indexPath
}



@IBAction func cancelAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismiss()
}

@IBAction func confirmAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    //TODO : add confirmAction

    if selectedContact != nil
    {
        self.dismiss()
        if delegate.respondsToSelector(Selector("addressSelectPopup:"))
        {
            delegate.addressSelectPopup(selectedContact!)
        }
    }
}}
```

///Update 1

I create a new ViewController (called PopupVC) using the Delegate & DataSource code above.

Way1 : I present the PopupVC from the rootView.

Result : it works fine.

Way2 : I add the View of PopupVC as a subView to rootView, and also add PopupVC as a childViewController to rootView.

Result : Swiping the cell will call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Tapping only makes the cell be highlighted.

///Update 2

I just noticed that the rootView is presented by another View.

Comment: Have you linked delegate to something in interface builder, that could interfere ? Does datasource is set in interface builder ?

Comment: @Justa Yes, and also programmatically. I also checked the delegate in cellForRowAtIndex and it is connected.But not called...

Answer (score 2):

First delete tap gesture of your subview before calling the *popoverview*. Then only call your `UITableViewDelegate` inside the popoverview.
To remove gesture from you view, use this code:

```
self.view.gestureRecognizers?.forEach(self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(_:))
self.view.addSubview(self.customView.view)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your class :

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

Comment: The delegate is connected. But not called.

Comment: Ok,I thought It wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

Well you shouldn't have delegate and datasource connected both in interface builder and programmatically. 
I believe one is badly set and is interfering with the other.

What you can do is try removing the link in interface builder, check what happens and if it is not working add them again but remove the link in the code.

Comment: I tried , but still not working... datasource is fine, just the delegate not works...

Comment: When I swipe the cell, it will call the didSelectRowAtIndexPath. When click, it only got highlighted and can not be selected. Could it be some hint?

Comment: @StevenJiang hmm that is strange. Do you have a view above that handle a click ? Or have you implemented a `UIGestureRecognizer` ?

Comment: No, I just connected the tableView and some IBAction. I just noticed that the rootView that pops this view is embed to a ContainerView. Is it will cause this kind of problem??

Comment: Sorry, the rootView is presented by another View actually